Recurrence Relation Solution
Show that the solution to the recurrence relation $h_n = (2n - 2) h_{n-2} + 3 h_{n-1} \quad \text{for } n \geq 2, \quad h_0 = 1, \quad h_1 = 3 \ $ is  $h_n = \frac{5^n + 2 \cdot 3^n + 1}{4} $. I have tried a few approaches, but none have gotten me the solution. I tried playing around using induction, but in the induction step I ended up with many terms with an $n$ that need to be made equal to a power of 5. I also tried using generating functions and exponential generating functions, but I couldn't make those work either. Any ideas on how to solve this?

This is perhaps not what was wanted, but a perfectly valid solution would be simply to show the given solution satisfies the recurrence relation.

@MichaelCohen That's basically what's involved in the induction step. The reason I was having trouble showing the solution satisfied the recurrence relation is that when you plug stuff in, one one side there are a bunch of terms multiple by n, and on the other side is just powers of 2 and 3. I couldn't figure out the algebra to show one side was equal to another.

Please do not delete questions unnecessarily, @SkinnyKevin.

The proposed solution is wrong. $h_2=11$, $h_3=45$ are ok, but
$$h_4=201\ne\frac{5^4+2\cdot3^4+1}4.$$
